# Memory leak when using threads and tkinter

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x, memory-leaks, tkinter

I have this "game thing" I've been working on for a while. It works perfectly, except that when I close the GUI whithout having finished the game, it keeps running on the background, (like if it was memory leaking, even though "real" memory leaking doesn't work that way).

This game runs (or in theory it should) on two threads, one for the GUI and another for the game itself, after some research I've found out I could use the `.protocol()` method on my root widget to execute `raise SystemExit` to ensure all threads were terminated when the GUI was closed. But it appears not to be working and I have no clue why. Here's the code:

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
from tkinter import Tk, Label, Entry, Button, W, E, END
from threading import Thread
from random import randint
class GUI(Thread):
    tentativas = []
    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(Thread)
        self.start()
        self.valor = randint(0, 100)
        self.vidas = 6
        self.venceu = False
        self.entry, self.aux = -128, -128
        while self.vidas > 0:
            self.vidas -= 1
            while True:
                if self.entry != self.aux:
                    break
            self.aux = self.entry
            if self.entry == self.valor:
                self.txt01.config(text = "Congrats, you won!", fg = "green")
                self.venceu = True
                self.txt02.config(text = '')
                break
            elif self.entry > self.valor:
                self.txt01.config(text = 'Too big, try again.')
            else:
                self.txt01.config(text = 'Too small, try again.')
            self.txt02.config(text = str(self.vidas) + ' Chances restantes.')
        if self.venceu != True:
            self.txt01.config(text = 'You ran out of lives, game over!')
            self.txt02.config(text = 'The number was ' + str(self.valor) + '.')
    def run(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.title("Lottery")
        self.txt00 = Label(self.root, text = "Welcome, insert a number ranging from 0 to 100:")
        self.txt00.grid(sticky = W, columnspan = 4)
        self.txt01 = Label(self.root, text = " ")
        self.txt01.grid(row = 1, column = 0, columnspan = 4, sticky = W)
        self.txt02 = Label(self.root, text ="6 Tentativas restantes.")
        self.txt02.grid(row = 4, columnspan = 2, sticky = E)
        self.inp00 = Entry(self.root)
        self.inp00.grid(row = 2,columnspan = 2,column = 1,sticky = W)
        self.but00 = Button(self.root, text = "Try!", command = self.chutar)
        self.root.bind("<Return>", self.chutar)
        self.but00.grid(row = 2, column = 3)
        self.root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.killGUI)
        self.root.mainloop()
    def chutar(self, args = None):
        self.pular = True
        try:
            self.chute = int(self.inp00.get())
        except ValueError:
            self.txt01.config(text = "Invalid entry, try again!", fg = "red")
            self.pular = False
        finally:
            self.inp00.delete(0, END)
        if self.pular:
            if self.chute in range(101) and self.chute not in self.tentativas:
                self.entry = self.chute
                self.tentativas.append(self.entry)    
            else:
                self.var = "Invalid entry, try again!"
                self.txt01.config(text = self.var, fg = "red")
    def killGUI(self):
        raise SystemExit
k = GUI()
```

I really don't know why the "killGUI" function isn't working, please help me!

Answer (score 0):

(As far as I know Tkinter is NOT threadsafe. This may cause this problem. So using threads with Tkinter isn't a great idea. I'm not even sure that you really need multithreading for this.)

Edit: Seems like you are just killing your childthread with this, the mainthread is still running.

But to solve your problem, one way is to force-"kill" the whole processtree. All you need is your script pid and a subprocess function. Try this code in your `killGUI`:

```
def killGUI(self):
    try:
        subprocess.call(['taskkill', '/F', '/T', '/PID', str(os.getpid())])
        print("Process killed: %s " % str(os.getpid()))
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)
```

This will kill your thread for sure.